# PHP datetime sub issue

Tags: php, datetime

```
$currentDT = new \DateTime(); 
$filterRange = new \DateInterval('PT30S'); 
$filterDate = $currentDT->sub($filterRange); 
var_dump($currentDT); 
var_dump($filterDate);
```

OUTPUT:

```
object(DateTime)[246]
  public 'date' => string '2011-12-10 15:53:42' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/New_York' (length=16)
object(DateTime)[246]
  public 'date' => string '2011-12-10 15:53:42' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/New_York' (length=16)
```

$currentDT and $filterDate are the same...even though they should be 30s different. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour, the subtraction acts on the original object which is then returned.  This can be seen by the `246` in the `var_dump()` outputs, denoting that they're one and the same object.

If you wish to keep the original object untouched, you'll need to [`clone`](http://php.net/clone) it before doing the subtraction.

```
$currentDT   = new \DateTime('2011-12-13 14:15:16');
$filterRange = new \DateInterval('PT30S');
$filterDate  = clone $currentDT;
$filterDate->sub($filterRange);
var_dump($currentDT, $filterDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime::sub` changes the date in the current object, and returns a copy of it for method chaining. So, in your example, you are changing the date of both objects, so both will be set to 30 seconds ago.

Try this - it uses two separately initialized objects for the comparison:

```
$current1 = new \DateTime();
$current2 = new \DateTime();

$filterRange = new \DateInterval('PT30S'); 
$current2->sub($filterRange); 
var_dump($current1);  // Should return the current time
var_dump($current2);  // Should return the current time - 30 seconds
```

or, as @salathe points out, use the  `clone` keyword of course.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to go is cloning instead of creating 2 consecutive isntances of datetime, because there is a chance that instance1 and instance2 are not equal depending on the processing speed of the server.