# How to deduct time in php 24 hours format

Tags: php, date, time

How to subtract `00:00:00` example with 1 hour?

I've tried:

```
$minus1=strtotime(00:00:00)-strtotime('-1 hour');
```

but instead of an answer of `23:00:00`, I got `-1502671524` instead.

Comment: Perhaps try to format your strtotime() result to the desired time format?  Did you look in the online manuals `date()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP datetime sub issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459813/php-datetime-sub-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateTime and DateInterval option to do in PHP.

```
    $date = new DateTime('00:00:00');
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H00M'));
    echo $date->format('H:i:s') . "\n";
```

The P stands for Period.  The T stands for Timespan. H stands for Hour to reduce and finally M stands for Minutes to reduce.

See [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [DateTime::sub](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php), and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) in the PHP manual. You'll have to set the `DateTime` to the appropriate date and time, of course.